# Specifying members of a given sequence with a Turing Machine

Tags: algorithm, math, turing-machines

One question I came across was, given a binary sequence a_0, ..., a_{n-1} how many transitions does it take such that when given a non-negative integer i it outputs a_i if i < n and 0 otherwise. You can assume the input starts with a 1 unless i is 0.

Using https://martinugarte.com/turingmachine/ I simulated the following Turing machines to try and get an idea for how many states this should take

Sequence with n=2, 5 transitions

```
//Sequence is 0,1
name: Sequence
init: one
accept: end

one,0
end,0,-

one,1
two,_,>

two,_
end,1,-

two,0
end,0,-

two,1
end,0,-
```

Sequenced with n=3, 8 transitions

```
//Sequence is 0,1,0
name: Sequence
init: one
accept: end

one,0
end,0,-

one,1
two,_,>

two,_
end,1,-

two,0
three,_,>

two,1
end,0,-

three,_
end,0,-

three,0
end,0,-

three,1
end,0,-
```

Sequence with n=4, 11 transitions

```
//Sequence is 0,1,0,1
name: Sequence
init: one
accept: end

one,0
end,0,-

one,1
two,_,>

two,_
end,1,-

two,0
three0,_,>

two,1
three1,_,>

three0,_
end,0,-

three0,0
end,0,-

three0,1
end,0,-

three1,_
end,1,-

three1,0
end,0,-

three1,1
end,0,-
```

From this I'd guess that it is roughly O(n) states required to specify a sequence n long. Can you prove this?

Comment: In the n=3 example, couldn't you have `two,0:end,0,-` and do without `three` entirely? And when you say "states", do you mean "transitions"?

Comment: @Beta that works thanks. Wouldn't work for a genetic sequence though so I'll leave my example as is. I was taught that a state is basically the same as a transition. Is this wrong in modern literature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true by induction. Take the base case to be n=2, the following Turing machine can easily be modified to work for any length 2 sequence

```
//Sequence is 0,1
name: Sequence 
init: one
accept: end

one,0 end,0,-

one,1 two,_,>

two,_ end,1,-

two,0 end,0,-

two,1 end,0,-
```

Now for the inductive step assume it works for length n and is ordered like above. If we specify them like `six0101` for `10101x` we replace the smallest one that goes to end, sorted by the number that the transition acts on at that point, for instance,

```
six0101,0
end,0,-
```

acts on `101010`. Make this transition go to three new transitions, in the example it would go to `seven01010` which on blank would output a_n and stop. On 0,1 it would output 0 and stop. This adds 3 transitions to the Turing machine. satisfying the inductive step.

In fact this proves that for binary Turing machines the states needed have an upper bound of 3n-1 transitions. This can be generalized to c-character Turing machines with the following upper bound (c+1)n-1